# Limit user access to layers using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, openlayers, geoserver

I am working on a WebGIS project which contains a lot of layers which are served using GeoServer. The layers are accessed using WMS through OpenLayers 3.

The list of all the layers are stored in a Postgres table something like this.

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | layername | layerowner |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | layer1    | user1      |
|  2 | layer2    | user2      |
|  3 | layer3    | user3      |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

This list is important as the javascript file that loads the layers is generated using that table. (I'm not sure if it's a proper way of doing this).

```
var lyr1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'LAYERNAME',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WORKSPACE/wms',
            params:{
                'LAYERS': 'LAYERNAME',
                'TILED': true
            },
            serverType: 'geoserver'
        })),
});
```

I have another table for users something like this.

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | username | userlevel |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | user1    | admin     |
|  2 | user2    | standard  |
|  3 | user3    | standard  |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

I need to limit the access to layers based on user. I initially thought of using `userlevel` to limit the access to the layers but users with the same user level will have access to all the layers of that level. But I need something like providing the access to a particular layer for a particular user. By default admin should be able to access all the layers but `user1` can only access the layers for which he was granted access. I don't have knowledge on how to do this and I can't think of a way to do it. Any help or idea on how to do this will be appreciated.

**Edit:** Tried adding a column for each user in the table and setting a boolean for checking if he had access. I guess this is not a proper solution as I need to provide a column for every user. Here's the SQL Fiddle.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/819d5/4).

Comment: Row-level security?

Comment: I guess so. I use session variables to check which user is logged in and the user should be able to access only the layers assigned to him (rows in the layers table?).  I think I need some method that restricts the users listed in the users table from accessing all the layers (rows?) in layers table.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoServer directly supports [per user layer access](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html) as part of its [standard security model](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/index.html). So rather than hand rolling your own solution you should use the provided mechanism which is tested. This allows you to have security set using users, groups and roles, which should be plenty of flexibility for your needs.

Specifically GeoServer provides [a JDBC authentication option](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/providers.html#jdbc-authentication) to use your existing tables.

As for getting a list of layers you should request and parse the getCapabilities document which will only include the layers a user is authorised to see.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going through the links provided. I think this should help. Will try it out but should I be creating new GeoServer for each user that accesses my application? or is there a way to allow the same username and password they use to login to my application?

Comment: GeoServer provides a JDBC authentication option to use your existing tables http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/providers.html#jdbc-authentication

Comment: Can you add this in the answer too? And thank you I guess this solves my problem.